# How can i keep a data table thorough out my page?

Tags: asp.net

Hii,

I have a data table, and this datatable will be dynamically manipulated. After certain manipulation at the end we will populate that to the database. Which state mechanism can i use for this to retain. I have tried both Session and ViewState but ViewState can't use with AJAX rich appplications. Session will be clear after the user session. i can't afford both these difficulties. Does any other mechanism to keep the datatable through out the page.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to persist the data after the user session ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Application variables](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/324.html) if you need to persist state between users or sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [storing your Session state in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604)? <strike>This would avoid the timeout of the session in IIS.</strike>

Comment: SqlServer sessions does not avoid timeouts, it is just a different method of persistence that survives AppPool resets, and works better in load balanced scenarios, as well as offloading burden of storage from in process memory.

Comment: @OrbMan: really worthy of a downvote, though? The OP is looking for a way to save state. Session state in SQL Server is a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the ASP.NET runtime cache?

```
 Cache["Foo"] = bar;
```

This cache is kept in memory and "lives" as long as the host application does.